# Unable to access accounts hash cache path: source(create_dir_all) - I/O error: Permission denied (os error 13), file: /mnt/ledger/accounts_hash_cache

Tags: validator

Getting this error:

```
Unable to access accounts hash cache path: source(create_dir_all) - I/O error: Permission denied (os error 13), file: /mnt/ledger/accounts_hash_cache
```

While trying to run a testnet solana validator on a cgp instance. I have an SSD with 2TB for the ledge, one with 500GB for the accounts, i've followed the guide from:

https://docs.solana.com/validator/get-started/setup-a-validator

That's my `validator.sh`:

```
exec solana-validator \
    --identity validator-keypair.json \
    --vote-account vote-account-keypair.json \
    --known-validator 5D1fNXzvv5NjV1ysLjirC4WY92RNsVH18vjmcszZd8on \
    --known-validator 7XSY3MrYnK8vq693Rju17bbPkCN3Z7KvvfvJx4kdrsSY \
    --known-validator Ft5fbkqNa76vnsjYNwjDZUXoTWpP7VYm3mtsaQckQADN \
    --known-validator 9QxCLckBiJc783jnMvXZubK4wH86Eqqvashtrwvcsgkv \
    --only-known-rpc \
    --log /home/sol/solana-validator.log \
    --ledger /mnt/ledger \
    --accounts /mnt/accounts \
    --rpc-port 8899 \
    --dynamic-port-range 8000-8020 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint.testnet.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint2.testnet.solana.com:8001 \
    --entrypoint entrypoint3.testnet.solana.com:8001 \
    --expected-genesis-hash 4uhcVJyU9pJkvQyS88uRDiswHXSCkY3zQawwpjk2NsNY \
    --wal-recovery-mode skip_any_corrupted_record \
    --limit-ledger-size
```

My disks:

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0   10G  0 disk 
├─sda1    8:1    0  9.9G  0 part /
├─sda14   8:14   0    3M  0 part 
└─sda15   8:15   0  124M  0 part /boot/efi
sdb       8:16   0    2T  0 disk /mnt/ledger
sdc       8:32   0  500G  0 disk /mnt/accounts
```

Answer (score 2):

The user starting the validator doesn't have access to the directory in question.

Did you maybe forget to run this command? `sudo chown -R sol:sol /mnt/ledger`

Comment: Just did:

sudo chown -R sol:sol /mnt/ledger

i've done before but did again just to make sure

Unable to access accounts hash cache path: source(create_dir_all) - I/O error: Permission denied (os error 13), file: /mnt/ledger/accounts_hash_cache

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 3 dfb_rodrigo_burgos sol  4096 Sep 20 18:07 ledger these are the permission on sol user

Comment: `sudo chown -R sol:sol /mnt/ledger/accounts_hash_cache` Try this

Comment: chown: cannot access '/mnt/ledger/accounts_hash_cache': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

The `chown` has to happen after the `mount`. Try this -

###### You have to mount the drive first:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt/ledger
```

###### Then change the ownership of the directory to your sol user:

```
sudo chown -R sol:sol /mnt/ledger
```

You have to do the above from the admin/main user. You can do the same for `/mnt/accounts` also but be sure to change the mount point.

Also doing just this won't be enough. You want to make sure thats in `fstab` too or it wont get mounted if the node reboots. You can try this -

```
/dev/sdb    /mnt/ledger    ext4    defaults    0    1
/dev/sdc    /mnt/accounts  ext4    defaults    0    1
```

Comment: Already mounted both drivers.

Comment: Did you setup the `fstab`